# In sequence, number is preceived as NA

Tags: r

I want to create a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), it's pretty straight forward but when I try to call all values in the right locations, like I do in `seq.int` below, I get an error message that's quite strange, as `prime * 2` is definitely just a number.

```
q4 <- function (n) {
  art <- rep (TRUE, n)
  art [1] <- FALSE
  prime <- 2
  for (i in 2:n) {
    if (i^2 > n) {break}
    else {
      art [seq.int (2 * prime, length (art), prime)] <- FALSE
      prime <- min (which (art [prime + 1:length (art)]))
    }
  }
  art
}

q4(20)
Error in seq.int(from = 2 * prime, to = length(art), by = prime) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning message:
In min(which(art[prime + 1:length(art)])) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I'd love to know what in this expression make R refer to it as NA.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error due to following problem, if `art` is full of `FALSE`, then the result of `prime <- min (which (art [prime + 1:length (art)]))` is `Inf` => `Inf * 2 = Inf == NaN`.

Comment: and `art` _is_ full of `FALSE` at some point.  Try adding in the line `cat(i, prime, "\n     ", art, "\n")` as the first line of your for loop.